# Connecting/Tunneling through a proxy so you appear to be connecting from another country(iOS)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm interested in trying to make a connection from within my app to a proxy somewhere in the UK so I can listen to radio streams there that are blocked from the UK.

What would it take technically to implement this?
Is this even possible with the API available within iOS?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a VPN for this kind of thing. I have (of course) never done this myself but you could use OpenVPN in theory. I don't know how useful [this](http://wiki.hidemyass.com/OpenVPN_setup_on_iPad_iPhone_iTouch) is and there is a writeup [here](http://www.softwaretochangeipaddress.com/software-to-change-ip-address-on-iphone-and-ipad/) to explain why I say this. You need to jailbreak your phone.

Comment: Hi Paul, that's a pity you need to jailbreak.